# How to show current message in a running app to current screen (TTY 1-6 or shellinabox, ...)

Tags: screen

File test-screen.sh content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :
do
date
sleep 1
done
```

If I run test-screen.sh in TTY1 (or auto start as service) then I wanna show loop message on TTY3 (or shellinabox) where I'm watching.
How to do it? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Identify each of your terminals with the command

```
tty
```

Suppose your terminals are `/dev/tty1` and `/dev/tty3`, and the same user is logged in on both terminals, then you can use normal redirection techniques, e.g.

```
ls > /dev/tty3
```

to redirect output to `tty3`, or `tee` to redirect output both to the current and the other terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question:
Run bellow command on tty1:

```
screen -S test-screen-name test-screen.sh
```

if I wanna show this running app on tty2, shellinabox,... I can run this command:

```
screen -x -S test-screen-name
```

But now have new problem:
If I set this command to service and enable this service, an error when PC power on (if I run without service it is normally, systemctl start auto-oc.service is this error):

```
● auto-oc.service - auto-oc.service------------------------------
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/auto-oc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-06-17 15:29:38 +07; 2min 4s ago
  Process: 608 ExecStart=/auto-power/bin/auto-oc.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 608 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[787]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[792]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -i 0 -pl 60.00
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[792]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[792]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[794]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/screen -S miner /miners/nbminer/42.2/nbminer -a ethash -o stratum+ssl://asia2.ethermine.org:5555 -o1 stratum+tcp://asia1.ethermine.org:4444 -o2 stratum+tcp://asia2.ethermine.org:14444 -u 0xddA50aE94Dd517423cd29Ec4837c61e9E9A62518.rig000 -u1 0xddA50aE94Dd517423cd29Ec4837c61e9E9A62518.rig000 -u2 0xddA50aE94Dd517423cd29Ec4837c61e9E9A62518.rig000 --mt 1 --fee 1 -log --api 127.0.0.1:22333
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[794]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 auto-oc.sh[608]: Must be connected to a terminal.
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 sudo[794]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 systemd[1]: auto-oc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 17 15:29:38 rig000 systemd[1]: auto-oc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```